Collapsible Banner covers the keyboard when displayed
When showing Collapsible Banner at the same time as using the device's keyboard, the keyboard is behind the ad.
How to make the device's keyboard always appear at the top.
I tested on some real devices but still got the error.
Is there a way to make the keyboard appear above the Collapsible Banner? Because it is affecting the user's experience
google_mobile_ads: ^5.1.0
Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale en-VN)
Dart version 3.4.1
DevTools version 2.34.3

s there a way to make the keyboard appear above the Collapsible Banner? Because it is affecting the user's experience

Did you try collapsing the banner when clicked on textfields?

Thanks for answering.
When collapsing, there are no problems at all.
But the request can still show the floating keyboard on the banner when it is not collapsed.
